# How to multithread my for loop in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, performance, list, for-loop

I've got a fairly simple for loop that I want to hyperthread, but I am unsure on how. The for loop loops through every message in a list, and returns a bisect for each message, then checks if this bisect is larger than the previous ones. For information about the bisecting check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28932955/2169327) out

```
#Pseudo: For each AISmessagesList
messageFrequency.append(0)
for messageIndex in range(len(AISmessages)):
    frequency = bisect.bisect(AISmessages[messageIndex:], AISmessages[messageIndex]+86400)
    if messageFrequency[-1]<frequency:
        messageFrequency[-1] = frequency
```

My initial idea was to partition the array out, and just return the results from the bisect to an array - then find the max element in the array - but since the loop iterates on itself, I'm not quite sure on how this should be done. Should I maybe make two arrays, one with "starting points" and one array that this iterates over?

Comment: If this is for performance, forget it if you're using [CPython](http://www.python.org). The [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) means multithreading doesn't really increase performance.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Is it the same case with multiprocessing?

Comment: No, in fact the multiprocessing module even explicitly says that this is its use. "The multiprocessing package offers both local and remote concurrency, effectively side-stepping the Global Interpreter Lock by using subprocesses instead of threads. Due to this, the multiprocessing module allows the programmer to fully leverage multiple processors on a given machine. It runs on both Unix and Windows"